# htaccess redirection for a pattern

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I searched for a solution of my issue and tried several ways but none of them worked.

I am migrating my website to a new system and want to change the url structure too. But I couldnt find a solution for one of them which is the most important one.

It is an e-commerce site. All product page urls had domain.com/product/productname/ in the previous system and now I need them to go to domain.com/productname.html  . So the product part should be catched and redirected to the version without product/ .

Might be very simple too but I couldnt find a solution for that.

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: Is `product` a static text or something that will change for each product?

Comment: domain.com/**product**/productname.html  product is always same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/([^./]+)/?$ /$1.html
```

Comment: I made a mistake on the request path structure. I edited it now. Requested path is without .html at the end and the target should have the .html

Comment: Almost there but it created the target path productname/.html so the / should be gone